# Convert year-month-day to weekday in file name

Tags: rename, filenames, date

I need to take the following filename structure and rename to the appropriate day of the week:

```
GMT20161003-randomtext.mp4
```

would end up as `monday.mp4`

I have a lot of these files in various subdirectories so it would be better if it could be run recursively...

Comment: Use this as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787530/convert-from-yyyymmdd-to-day-month-date-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)GMT(<->)*(.mp4)(#qD.)' '$1${(L)$(
  strftime %A "$(strftime -r %Y%m%d $2)")}$3'
```

Remove the `-n` to actually do the renaming.

- `<->` matches any decimal number.
- That second `(...)` is captured in `$2`, `(.mp4)` in `$3` and the directory (`(**/)`, recursive) in `$1`.
- `(#qD.)` is a glob qualifier that only selects *regular* files (`.`: not directories, nor symlinks nor fifos/devices...) and also traverse hidden directories (`D` for dotfile/dotdir).
- `${(L)...}`: converts the expansion to lower-case.
- `strftime -r %Y%m%d`: reverse-strftime (strptime) to convert the date to an epoch time.
- `strftime %A ...`: format time for that epoch time with %A being for the full week day. Beware it's locale-dependany. (in a French locale, you'll get the French week day).

On a GNU system, and with the GNU shell (`bash`), you could do:

```
find . -name 'GMT*-*.mp4' -type f -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    base=${file##*/}
    date=${base#GMT}
    date=${date%%-*}
    wday=$(date -d "$date" +%A)
    echo mv -i "$file" "${file%/*}/${wday,,}.mp4"
  done' bash {} +
```

(remove `echo` to perform the operation).

`${var,,}` being `bash`'s operator to convert to lower case. `date -d` being the GNU `date` way to parse a date (like `strftime -r` above).

While `zmv` would check for conflicts before starting renaming any file, this one wouldn't. So we add a `-i` above to at least give you a chance of avoiding clobbering files. GNU `mv` has a `-v` option to tell it to show what it's going to do which may be useful to revert the command later if anything went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will check these out and then report back!

Comment: You are my hero today - used the second solution in a .sh script - just tried on one file in one folder and it worked perfectly.  Thank you so much again!!